# If $|a_0|<|a_n|$, Prove that $P(z)=\sum^{n}_{k=0}a_kz^k$ has at least one zero inside the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $|a_0|<|a_n|$, Prove that $P(z)=\sum^{n}_{k=0}a_kz^k$ has at least one zero inside the unit disk.

My thoughts so far: I defined $h(z)=a_0$ and $q(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+...+a_nz^n$, and tried to show that on the unit circle $|q(z)|>|h(z)| \ \  (*)$ and then the result follows immediately using Rouche's theorem, but I think $(*)$ is not true necessarily although we have that $|a_0|<|a_n|$.

Any hints or ideas is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result is surely true for n = 1.

Let us write $|a_0| < |a_k|$ is "the condition".

Every polynomial $P_k(z)$ of degree k can be written as a product of linear factors.  Suppose P$_k$ satisfies the condition.  We claim that at least one of its linear factors also satisfies the condition.

Suppose those linear factors are {$c_jz + d_j$}, for j = 1 to k.  Then $a_k = \prod c_j$ and $a_0 = \prod d_j$.  We are given than $|a_k| > |a_0|$, so that $|\prod c_j| > |\prod d_j|$.  This implies that $|c_j|$ > $|d_j|$ for at least one of the j's.  That linear factor has a zero inside the unit circle and thus so does $P_k$.

Answer (score 2):

|Product of zeros|=$\left|\dfrac{a_0}{a_n}\right|<1,$ this implies at least one zero lies inside in unit disk $|z|<1.$